# V8 javascript how to make asynchronous calls

Tags: c++, asynchronous, v8, embedded-v8, libv8

I've been trying to figure out how to make asynchronous calls in V8, without luck. The example javascript code I'm trying to have run is:

```
function test ()
{
    logMessage ('asynchronous call made!');
}
saveFunc(test);
```

The saveFunc function is supposed to save the test function for use when the C++ code calls it later after the script is ran. Everytime I try this it crashes when I try to execute the function that was saved. What am I doing wrong?

I've copied my entire example code below. Thanks in advance.

**Example Code:**

```
// Copyright 2015 the V8 project authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "libplatform/libplatform.h"
#include "v8.h"

using namespace v8;

Local<Context> context;
v8::Local<v8::Function> savedFunc;

class ArrayBufferAllocator : public v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator {
public:
    virtual void* Allocate(size_t length) {
        void* data = AllocateUninitialized(length);
        return data == NULL ? data : memset(data, 0, length);
    }
    virtual void* AllocateUninitialized(size_t length) { return malloc(length); }
    virtual void Free(void* data, size_t) { free(data); }
};

std::string parseV8Value(v8::Local<v8::Value> str)
{
    if (str.IsEmpty() == true)
        return ("");

    v8::String::Utf8Value newStr(str);

    return (*newStr);
}

void logMessage(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &args)
{
    std::string applicationSource = parseV8Value(args[0]);
    std::cout << applicationSource << "\n";
}

void getInput(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &args)
{
    v8::Local<v8::Function> func = v8::Local<v8::Function>::Cast (args[0]);
    std::string input = "";

    std::cin >> input;

    v8::Local<v8::Value> *args2 = new v8::Local<v8::Value>[1];
    args2[0] = v8::String::NewFromUtf8 (args.GetIsolate (), input.c_str ());

    func->Call (context->Global (), 1, args2);

    delete []args2;
    args2 = NULL;
}

void saveFunc(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &args)
{
    savedFunc = v8::Local<v8::Function>::Cast(args[0]);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Initialize V8.
    V8::InitializeICU();
    V8::InitializeExternalStartupData(argv[0]);
    Platform* platform = platform::CreateDefaultPlatform();
    V8::InitializePlatform(platform);
    V8::Initialize();

    // Create a new Isolate and make it the current one.
    ArrayBufferAllocator allocator;
    Isolate::CreateParams create_params;
    create_params.array_buffer_allocator = &allocator;
    Isolate* isolate = Isolate::New(create_params);
    {
        Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);

        // Create a stack-allocated handle scope.
        HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);

        // Create a new context.
        v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate> global = v8::ObjectTemplate::New(isolate);
        global->Set(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "logMessage"),
            v8::FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, logMessage));
        global->Set(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "getInput"),
            v8::FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, getInput));
        global->Set(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "saveFunc"),
            v8::FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, saveFunc));
        context = Context::New(isolate, NULL, global);

        // Enter the context for compiling and running the hello world script.
        Context::Scope context_scope(context);

        // Create a string containing the JavaScript source code.
        Local<String> source =
            String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, 
            "function test (){ logMessage ('asynchronous call made!'); }saveFunc(test);",,
                NewStringType::kNormal).ToLocalChecked();

        // Compile the source code.
        Local<Script> script = Script::Compile(context, source).ToLocalChecked();

        // Run the script to get the result.
        Local<Value> result = script->Run(context).ToLocalChecked();

        v8::Local<v8::Value> *args = new v8::Local<v8::Value>[0];
        savedFunc->Call(context->Global(), 0, args);

        delete []args;
        args = NULL;
    }

    // Dispose the isolate and tear down V8.
    isolate->Dispose();
    V8::Dispose();
    V8::ShutdownPlatform();
    delete platform;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. is `saveFunc()` supposed to do the same thing as [`process.nextTick()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback_arg)?

Comment: You have to understand differenct between local and persistent handles: https://developers.google.com/v8/embed#handles-and-garbage-collection

Comment: Congradulations - you figured out one of the basics of JavaScript that escapes most people - concurrency and asynchronous calls don't come from JavaScript - they come from the host environment wrapping it like Chromium or Node - Node for example drives it with LibUV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so you have to use a Persistent handle when saving the function in saveFunc. Also, you have to make sure that when you're accessing context->Global, that you're still within the HandleScope. Here's the corrected code:

```
// Copyright 2015 the V8 project authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "libplatform/libplatform.h"
#include "v8.h"

using namespace v8;

Isolate* isolate = NULL;
Local<Context> context;
v8::Persistent<v8::Function> *savedFunc = NULL;

class ArrayBufferAllocator : public v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator {
public:
    virtual void* Allocate(size_t length) {
        void* data = AllocateUninitialized(length);
        return data == NULL ? data : memset(data, 0, length);
    }
    virtual void* AllocateUninitialized(size_t length) { return malloc(length); }
    virtual void Free(void* data, size_t) { free(data); }
};

std::string parseV8Value(v8::Local<v8::Value> str)
{
    if (str.IsEmpty() == true)
        return ("");

    v8::String::Utf8Value newStr(str);

    return (*newStr);
}

void logMessage(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &args)
{
    std::string applicationSource = parseV8Value(args[0]);
    std::cout << applicationSource << "\n";
}

void getInput(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &args)
{
    v8::Local<v8::Function> func = v8::Local<v8::Function>::Cast (args[0]);
    std::string input = "";

    std::cin >> input;

    v8::Local<v8::Value> *args2 = new v8::Local<v8::Value>[1];
    args2[0] = v8::String::NewFromUtf8 (args.GetIsolate (), input.c_str ());

    func->Call (context->Global (), 1, args2);

    delete []args2;
    args2 = NULL;
}

void saveFunc(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &args)
{
    v8::Local<v8::Function> func = v8::Local<v8::Function>::Cast(args[0]);
    savedFunc = new v8::Persistent<v8::Function>();
    savedFunc->Reset(isolate, func);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Initialize V8.
    V8::InitializeICU();
    V8::InitializeExternalStartupData(argv[0]);
    Platform* platform = platform::CreateDefaultPlatform();
    V8::InitializePlatform(platform);
    V8::Initialize();

    // Create a new Isolate and make it the current one.
    ArrayBufferAllocator allocator;
    Isolate::CreateParams create_params;
    create_params.array_buffer_allocator = &allocator;
    isolate = Isolate::New(create_params);
    {
        Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);

        // Create a stack-allocated handle scope.
        HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);

        // Create a new context.
        v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate> global = v8::ObjectTemplate::New(isolate);
        global->Set(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "logMessage"),
            v8::FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, logMessage));
        global->Set(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "getInput"),
            v8::FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, getInput));
        global->Set(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "saveFunc"),
            v8::FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, saveFunc));
        context = Context::New(isolate, NULL, global);

        // Enter the context for compiling and running the hello world script.
        Context::Scope context_scope(context);

        // The "asynchronous" javascript call to make
        Local<String> source =
            String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, 
    "function test (){ logMessage ('asynchronous call made!'); }saveFunc(test);",
                NewStringType::kNormal).ToLocalChecked();

        // Compile the source code.
        Local<Script> script = Script::Compile(context, source).ToLocalChecked();

        // Run the script to get the result.
        Local<Value> result = script->Run(context).ToLocalChecked();

        v8::Local<v8::Value> *args = new v8::Local<v8::Value>[0];
        v8::Local<v8::Value> recv = context->Global();
        v8::Local<v8::Function> func = savedFunc->Get(isolate);
        func->Call (recv, 0, args);

        delete savedFunc;
        savedFunc = NULL;

        delete []args;
        args = NULL;
    }

    // Dispose the isolate and tear down V8.
    isolate->Dispose();
    V8::Dispose();
    V8::ShutdownPlatform();
    delete platform;
    return 0;
}
```